# WebSphere and Java 1.8 Upgrade causes java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: ant, java-8, websphere, xjc, xmlbeans

Recently I upgraded my WAS application to use JDK 1.8 provided by IBM. But when I try to build my application using Ant. I see the error

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Workspace\trunk\APPInstallation\build.xml:1132: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Failed to read external schema document "jar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.jaxb.tools.jar!/com/ibm/jtc/jax/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/xjc.xsd", because "jar" access is not allowed.

Total time: 29 seconds
```

I Googled a bit about it, and found that i have to create a jaxp.properties file in the jre/lib folder, which I did, with the value:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
```

but it still doesn't work. Any help with this would be welcome! This is area of the ant file where the error comes from:

```
<wsimport wsdl="${build.dir}/src/${wsdl.file}" destdir="build" wsdlLocation="file:/WEB-INF/wsdl/${wsdl.file}" failonerror="true">
    <depends dir="${build.dir}/src" includes="*.xsd" />
    <produces dir="${lib.dir}" includes="${webservice.name}${webservice.component}WSBeans.jar"/>
</wsimport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do nesting any of these inside your wsimport task resolve it?

```
<xjcarg value="-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all"/>
<arg value="-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all"/>
<arg value="-J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all"/>
```

Comment: None of the options worked. With the xjcarg I get the error:
`[wsimport] no such JAXB option: -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`